# Implementing useMemo the right way

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to understand the usage of useMemo. Since the object doesn't change, I thought I can improve performance by adding useMemo.
However as soon I add it here, I am being asked to add `findFloorPosition`. Once I did that my linter asks me to add `useCallback` to the `findFloorPosition` function.
Can you give me some advice what's the right way to implement `useMemo` here?

```
const location = useLocation();
const searchParams = parseQs(location.search);
const goto = searchParams?.goto;

const findFloorPosition = (elementId) => {
  for (const floor of blueprint) {
    for (const room of floor.rooms) {
      const foundElement = room.elements.find(
        (element) => element.id === elementId
      );
      if (foundElement) {
        return floor.position;
      }
    }
  }
};

const currentFloorPosition = useMemo(() => findFloorPosition(goto), [goto]);
```

Probably not relevant here, but here how the `blueprint` object looks like:

```
const blueprint = [
  {
    id: "4mD59WO",
    name: "AUDITORIUM",
    position: 1,
    rooms: [
      {
        id: "zR8Qgpj",
        name: "Audimax",
        subtitle: null,
        details: null,
        position: 0,
        elements: [
          {
            id: "1jLv04W",
            position: 0,
            type: "daily",
            element: "listing_large",
            properties: {
              meetingId: null,
              capacity: 6
            }
          },
          {
            id: "1jLv12W",
            position: 1,
            type: "daily",
            element: "listing_large",
            properties: {
              meetingId: null,
              capacity: 6
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "3mDd9WO",
    name: "FOYER",
    position: 0,
    rooms: [
      {
        id: "4R8Qgpj",
        name: "Speakers Table",
        subtitle: null,
        details: null,
        position: 0,
        elements: [
          {
            id: "2jLv04W",
            position: 0,
            type: "daily",
            element: "listing_large",
            properties: {
              meetingId: null,
              capacity: 6
            }
          },
          {
            id: "2jLv12W",
            position: 1,
            type: "daily",
            element: "listing_large",
            properties: {
              meetingId: null,
              capacity: 6
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: Are you asking how to implement this logic with `useMemo` or you asking what is the right decision here?

Comment: I think that useMemo makes sense here (it only has to render once since the object "blueprint" doesn't change). So I am more wondering about the logic how to implement it. E.g. do I also have to use `useCallback`.

Comment: @JoeyCoder your wording is confusing. Usually if you were trying to 'implement' something you'd be re-creating it, not *using* it. Your question seems to be about how to correctly *use* `useMemo`, not *implement* it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that you should memoize a value only if the dependency array values (the value of `goto`) not frequently change.

The warning occurs because the linter (`eslint`) only evaluates the semantics, it doesn't know that `findFloorPosition` is just a helper function.

So basically you need to inline the helper function like:

```
const currentFloorPosition = useMemo(() => {
  for (const floor of blueprint) {
    for (const room of floor.rooms) {
      const foundElement = room.elements.find(
        (element) => element.id === goto
      );
      if (foundElement) {
        return floor.position;
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}, [goto]);

// Or
const currentFloorPosition = useMemo(() => {
  const findFloorPosition = (elementId) => {
  for (const floor of blueprint) {
    for (const room of floor.rooms) {
      const foundElement = room.elements.find(
        (element) => element.id === elementId
      );
      if (foundElement) {
        return floor.position;
      }
    }
  }
};
  return findFloorPosition(goto);
}, [goto]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Shubham, just answered as well using `useCallback`. Is there any advantage in using useCallback as well, or should I just pick one based on preference. I assume useCallback makes sense if I use findFloorPosition several times in my component.

Comment: `useCallback` can be implemented with `useMemo` as stated in the docs. My answer based on your comment "So I am more wondering about the logic how to implement it"

Comment: And that the linter mentions `blueprint` is missing as dependency is fine in that case as I know it won't change?

Comment: I can't know where blueprint comes from, if it says its missing so you should do it. Seems like its a state or a prop and not a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

Since functional components rely heavily on closures, its extremely important that when you memoize functions, you are using the correct and updated values from the closures.

The reason `eslint` warns you to add `findFloorPosition` to dependency is to make sure that nothing within findFloorPosition refers to old values

The above code can be implemented like

```
const findFloorPosition = useCallback((elementId) => {
  for (const floor of blueprint) {
    for (const room of floor.rooms) {
      const foundElement = room.elements.find(
        (element) => element.id === elementId
      );
      if (foundElement) {
        return floor.position;
      }
    }
  }
}, [blueprint]);

const currentFloorPosition = useMemo(() => findFloorPosition(goto), [goto, findFloorPosition]);
```

Comment: Thank you Shubham. That was helpful. I will post one follow up question to Dennis answer as I wonder if there is any advantage of using `useCallback` vs just bringing the function in useMemo as he suggested.

Comment: useCallback comes in handy when you want to not just use the function within useMemo but also somewhere else in your code. You can obviously write the logic and the function within useMemo and avoid it as a dependency in case where you just use the function within usememo and do not plan to use it anywhere else in future too

Comment: Ok understood, that's what I was thinking. Thank you for the explanation. Very helpful!

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)